# layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf and layout_constraintRight_toRightOf don't make the view be as wide as the constraint

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

There are two widgets (`TextView`s in my example). The first widget has a fixed width, and the second widget should be as wide as the first one.

Consider the following code snippets:

**RelativeLayout.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="192dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:text="Short message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#aaa"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**ConstraintLayout.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="192dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:text="Short message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#aaa"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

As you can see in the second picture, the second widget is not as wide as the first widget. Why? I thought `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView"` would do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your second TextView as follows:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#aaa"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.486" />
```

set layout_width=0 matches the constraints, and you should not set the margin if you want to align the both textView

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try set `android:layout_width` to 0dp 
and `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"`. Also remove left and right margins.